# How to Comment: why does the linked name sometimes appear, but not always?

Tags: support, comment-replies

I've noticed that when I make a comment with "@user blah blah yada yada" it sometimes appears as "blah blah yada yada" whereas other times it appears as "@user blah blah yada yada".

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in how I point my comment to an intended user?

How should I formulate the comment so that the intended user sees the comment in their "responses" tab?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: See [Making your comments heard](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/making-your-comments-heard), [Weird reoccuring bug : @ someone.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/weird-reoccuring-bug-someone) and [When is @ ping necessary to cause comment notification to take place?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/when-is-ping-necessary-to-cause-comment-notification-to-take-place)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks! I will look into these links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This old MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97098/214632) gives a bit of information about this.  [This somewhat newer MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99389/214632) gives a hint of how this came about.  (Note that the thread the latter link is on is a **status-declined** feature request to not remove the @ part of a comment.)

Finally, just in case you want *even more* information about @ replies, [read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/214632).

Comment: Thanks. I look into your answer a bit later and accept it most likely...